# "Tabbing" between fields using TabIndex

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

## PROBLEM

In my **Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML Application using .NET 4.5** I'm trying to *"iterate"* through form. In other words, when the user presses *"Enter"* key, the focus changes to another `TextBox` or `PasswordBox`.

**HOW MY CODE LOOKS LIKE NOW**

XAML:

```
<TextBox TabIndex="0" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
<TextBox TabIndex="1" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
<TextBox TabIndex="2" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
<TextBox TabIndex="3" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
<TextBox TabIndex="4" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
....
```

C# CodeBehind:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
        int index = ((TextBox)sender).TabIndex + 1;
        //and here is what I've been missing
        //basically the code to select next tabindex
        //and set focus on it using Focus() method...
    }
}
```

## QUESTION

1. **HOW TO SELECT NEXT ELEMENT TO FOCUS ON BY TABINDEX???** I know I should probably use LINQ, to select all textboxes in the usercontrol and then select the one with tabindex index. I'm slowly figuring it on my own (and also by discussing it with people in the comments), but as it's taking me a long time I wrote the question :)

*(also, I was not sure how to name the question, feel free to rename it if you think your name fits it better)

## SOLUTION BASED ON SACHA's ANSWER

**LayoutRoot is the main grid of usercontrol**

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
        {
            int index = ((TextBox)sender).TabIndex + 1;
            var nextBox = LayoutRoot.Children.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault((x) => { return x.TabIndex == index; });

            if (nextBox != null)
            {
                nextBox.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I'm not the best at XAML, but in terms of question style I can't see the problem. It looks like you're approaching it in the same way I would - what are you unhappy with up to now? Your code comments appear to answer the question I thought you were asking.

Comment: The No.1 Question is "HOW TO SELECT NEXT ELEMENT TO FOCUS ON BY TABINDEX???" :)

Comment: Well you have the sender, so I assume there'll be a way of evaluating the value of an attribute/property (i.e. TabIndex). So all you need to do is increment the TabIndex to identify which TextBox should be 'next', and when your If statement you have there evaluates to true - focus on it.

Comment: the second and third ones are optional, in case there is someone really good who has his own easy foolproof way of doing this with diferent aproach.

Comment: @DeeMac and that's where I'm stuck and why i wrote the question.

Comment: There's never an easy foolproof way of doing things. If they are optional then how do you expect to determine which TextBox to focus on? EDIT: But I've just proposed an approach? What are you stuck on? If you're stuck on the specifics of what code would allow you to retrieve a control's property then I'd be inclined to suggest you haven't googled it yet.

Comment: Sometimes there is. I edited the question and removed the optional other two :) Yes you indeed did, (and so did I in my comments in the codebehind commentary), but I'm stuck on HOW EXACTLY? In other words: Could you please provide CODE EXAMPLE, since I'm n00b and don't know how?

Comment: I've been googling but didn't find what I needed, that might be given by the thing that I don't know how to name the problem properly, so asking is a bit difficult (english ain't my first language and even though I don't have problem with communication it's sometimes pretty hard to be exact)

Comment: Have you tried writing anything there? Do you know how to check the sender's `TabIndex`? Do you know how to find other elements on the page? Do you know how to focus on a particular control?

Comment: I know how to get senders tabindex, don't know how to find other elements on the page. I know how to focus on particular control.

Comment: To find other text boxes, use `VisualTreeHelper` to get all children from the parent container. Then cast them to check if they are of appropriate type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a possible implementation.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"
            >
    <TextBox TabIndex="0" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="1" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="2" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="3" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="4" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This next code assume that the ContentPanel contains only TextBox. It's up to you to add more smart code in it...

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
        var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
        var index = txtBox.TabIndex;

        var nextTextBox = ContentPanel.Children.Cast<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.TabIndex == index + 1);

        if (nextTextBox != null)
        {
            nextTextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was looking for the linq part mainly, as I don't know it that well. This helps me a lot.

Comment: +1. This is how I suspected the solution would look.

Comment: However in my implementation I changed the `Cast<textBox>` to `OfType<TextBox>()`.. :)

Answer (score 4):

If it helps to anyone, in 8.1 (don't know if it also works for 8) you can do like this:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
        FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You even don't need to name the `ContentPanel`:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
        var currentBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var container = currentBox.Parent;
        var index = currentBox.TabIndex + 1;
        var nextBox = container.ChildrenOfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(box => box.TabIndex == index);

        if (nextBox != null)
        {
            nextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void FocusOnTheNextTabIndex(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {

            int nextIndex = e.VisualElement.TabIndex + 1;
            var element = sender as Element;
            View nextElement = VerifyParent(element, nextIndex);
            if (nextElement != null)
                nextElement.Focus();
        }

 public View VerifyParent(Element element, int index)
        {
            var parent = element.Parent;
            if (parent.GetType() == typeof(StackLayout))
            {
                var stackParent = parent as StackLayout;
                var response = VerifyChildren(stackParent, index);
                if (response != null)
                    return response;
                else
                    return VerifyParent(parent, index);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public View VerifyChildren(StackLayout stackLayout, int index)
        {
            foreach (View view in stackLayout.Children)
            {
                if (view.TabIndex == index)
                    return view;
                else if (view.GetType() == typeof(StackLayout))
                {
                    var stack = view as StackLayout;
                    if (stack.Children.Any())
                    {
                        var response = VerifyChildren(stack, index);
                        if (response != null)
                            return response;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```