# How to set tab Index in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have 3 Textboxes in my app page and i want to set tab index for them so that when user presses return key from keyboard it should go to next text box.
I have set the Tab Index property of TextBox but its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Tabbing" between fields using TabIndex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229746/tabbing-between-fields-using-tabindex)

Comment: You can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229746/tabbing-between-fields-using-tabindex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for windows phone 8.1 app with the following code.

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key==Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        FocusManager.TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
    }
}
```

use the above method in KeyDown event of all TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible implementation.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"
            >
    <TextBox TabIndex="0" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="1" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="2" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="3" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox TabIndex="4" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This next code assume that the ContentPanel contains only TextBox. It's up to you to add more smart code in it...

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
        var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
        var index = txtBox.TabIndex;

        var nextTextBox = ContentPanel.Children.Cast<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.TabIndex == index + 1);

        if (nextTextBox != null)
        {
            nextTextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but its giving an error that KeyEventArgs is not a method or property of system.windows. input..

Comment: I am developing basic windows phone app not silverlight

Comment: Use this: KeyRoutedEventArgs

Comment: Exact copy paste http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229746/tabbing-between-fields-using-tabindex :(

Comment: now its giving an error that the name key does not exists in current context.  for this Key.Enter